Install package from source with tar (not tar.gz) file in R
I have an issue regarding the installation of packages from source in R v. 3.6.0.
I have two R packages which I want to install from source, one is the BiocGenerics from Bioconductor. I need them as dependencies for another software which hasnt been updated after R 3.6.0, which is why I need to use this older R version.
BiocGenerics is available as .tar file and .zip file, my other package only as .tar file.
I tried different solutions already:

In R via tools --> install packages --> select the .tar file

unpacked .tar file until penultimate layer (before vignette, R etc), compressed via 7zip to .zip file, then again as 1. in R via tools --> install packages --> select the .zip file
--> installation worked partially, but package is invalid



install.packages("C:/Users/Downloads/packagename.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
library(packagename)
Error in library(packagename) :
‘packagename’ is not a valid installed package


tried to compress via 7zip to .tar.7z file, then again as 1.


install.packages("D:/packagename_0.0.8.tar.7z", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'


tried to compress to .tgz file, then again 1.


install.packages("C:/Users/Downloads/biocgenerics_release_3_6.tgz", repos = NULL, type = .Platform$pkgType)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open compressed file 'biocgenerics_release_3_6.tgz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection


also the initial .zip file from bioGenerics didnt work in the installation

Do you have any ideas how I could proceed? Do I have to create a tar.gz file or can I install these packages differently, e.g. command line?
Thanks in advance

Where did get you get these files from? It sounds like they may not actually be in proper R package format. Maybe it's some git source dump or something. If it's raw source, you'll need to run something life R CMD build to turn it into a package. But without having any idea of what's actually in those files, it's hard to say what you need to do next.
